# How to target first matching descendant?

Tags: css

How do we target the first matching descendant, but not all other descendants further down the tree? e.g.,

if the HTML looks like

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!-- i want to target this td --> 
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <!-- but not this one -->
                <td>...</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've attempted the below, but it doesn't seem to work

```
.wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td {
  ...
}
```

Comment: What you have seems fine. How isn't it working?

Answer (score 1):

Inherited properties, such as color, would effect the children of the `td` even if they are not matched by the rule. In this case, 2nd `td` is a child of the 1st `td`.

You can reset inherited properties by `initial` on the children of the matched element. You can also set other properties on any effect children.

Example with color:

```css
.wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td {
  color: red;
}

.wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td > * {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!-- i want to target this td --> 
        <td>
          i want to target this td
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <!-- but not this one -->
                <td>but not this one</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't actually. I wanted to use color to refer to any inherited property, but somehow got distracted. Fixing.

Answer (score 0):

Your css will only target direct `td` descendants of any direct `tr` descendants of any direct `tbody` descendants of any direct `table` descendants of any `.wrapper` classed elements.

However, keep in mind that descendants of those `td`s selected may inherit styles from a parent or at least appear to inherit them.

Below is an example to show that you can style them differently.

```css
.wrapper > table > tbody > tr > td {
  background: red;
  padding: 4px;
  color: white;
}

td {
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#later-descendant {
  background: white;
  color: indigo;
  padding: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <!-- i want to target this td --> 
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <!-- but not this one -->
                <td>yellow</td>
                <td id='later-descendant'>indigo</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```